# How do you use the .replace() function in a specific column?

Tags: postgresql, csv, import, pgadmin

I´m preparing a .csv file through Python to use it on SQL to do some queries.
This is a dataset about some films and they have strings and floats.
I have in the .csv file some values in a float column that are empty values, expressed as `""` which are NaN if you read it through Python.
They are in 2 columns. In other different columns are strings. We have something like this:

```
films = [
   ["Intolerance: Love's Struggle Throughout the Ages""",385907.0],
   ["Over the Hill to the Poorhouse"3000000.0,100000.0],
   ["The Big Parade","",245000.0],
   ["Metropolis"26435.0,6000000.0],
   ["Pandora's Box"9950.0,""],
   ["The Broadway Melody",2808000.0,379000.0],
   ["Hell's Angels","",3950000.0],
   ["A Farewell to Arms","",800000.0]
    ]
    films_df = pd.DataFrame(
        films,
        columns=["title","gross","budget"],
    )
```

The idea is to put all the columns as types that can be readable for PG admin while importing, because the program does not accept `""` as a float type.
The problem is that the commas disappear in the other columns.

What I´ve tried is the following:

```
films = pd.read_csv("films.csv")
films_df = pd.DataFrame(films)

films_df["gross"] = films_df["gross"].replace('""',float('nan'))
films_df["budget"] = films_df["budget"].replace('""',float('nan'))
```

But they still changing all the `""` in the column `title` too. What I´m doing wrong?
Is there an easier way to import it to a Database?